Is it copyright infringement to make a combination of previous works?
For example, things such as Decade of Pop and r/place. Are these things copyright infringement (assuming that the authors do not have permission)? They are using copyrighted works, but I think it might fall under fair use. One can argue that they are transformative/a parody.
Location is United States.

I think the fair use argument would likely be that it only excerpts a tiny bit of each work, which is factor 3 "the amount and substantiality of the portion used". Also, the compilation of tiny bits shouldn't have any negative impact on the market of the original (factor 4), it might even enhance it as a form of free advertising.

I'm not sure I buy the parody angle, but that would have to be for a court to decide.
